# Guard equivalent for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, guard

Is the a PowerShell equivalent to Ruby's [guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard)?

The closest I've been able to find is Anthony Mastrean's ['lame' implementation](https://gist.github.com/AnthonyMastrean/4771515) (his words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a basic implementation started - https://github.com/smurawski/PowerShellGuard

You can watch files, directories, and use filters to limit files being monitored.  By default, it assumes Pester as the test framework, but you can use any test framework you can call from the command line.